# How to make inner if statement go to outer if statement's `else`?

Tags: if-statement

I'm having trouble with this piece:

```
if (a)
{
    if (b)    // when this check fails, I need to go v
        doSomething(); //                            v
}                      //                            v
else                   //                           < here
    doSomethingElse();
```

How do I do that?

**UPD:** if statements are nested because `a` checks if an object is not null, preventing exception caused by immediately checking for a null-object's parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do it short of employing `goto` where available is to guard the `else` branch of the outer `if` statement with a separate condition, rather than making it an `else` branch.

Assuming that there are calculations preceding the nested `if` that prevent you from performing both checks at once, you could do this:

```
bool done = false;
if (a) {
    ...
    if (b) {
        doSomething();
        done = true;
    }
}
if (!a && !done) {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

However, if the code in your conditions literally consists of calling functions `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse`, there is no harm in duplicating the invocation of the `doSomethingElse` function inside the nested `else` branch.

Comment: If you don't have code between the if (a) and if(b) like the OP has it, then the best answer would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11816104/11842333). It is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and the second condition will not be evaluated if the first is false.

Answer (score 2):

change to this:

```
if (a)
{
    if (b) {  
        doSomething();                            
    }
    else{
       doSomethingElse();
    }
}                      
else                  
    doSomethingElse();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(a && b)
  doSomething();
else
  doSomethingElse();
```

Comment: This is not always a valid answer. In my case, b is a user prompt asking for inputting True or False, and it should only be called if a is true

Comment: @Mehdi In if statements, if the first condition fails then the second condition will NEVER get evaluated. This works in every language I've worked with including C. It is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). IMO, this should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (a)
{
    if (b)    
        doSomething();                       
    else
        doeSomethingElse();
}                                             
else                                  
    doSomethingElse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this?

```
if (a && b) {
    doSomething();
}
else {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: You didn't specify that originally (you should edit your post instead of putting it in a comment). Also, why can't you check for null objects beforehand?